# Unexpected result of insertString method of NSMuttableString

Tags: ios7, nsstring, special-characters, nsmutablestring

Code is simple.

```
NSMutableString *tfContent = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
for (int i = 0; i<4; i++) {
    [tfContent  insertString:@"ę́" atIndex:i];
    NSLog(@"%@",tfContent);
}
```

Expected Result:

ę́
ę́ę́
ę́ę́ę́
ę́ę́ę́ę́

But It is giving result as

ę́
 ęę́́
 ęęę́́́
 ęęęę́́́́

Whats is problem here?

Comment: How are those spaces getting into the mutable string?

Comment: Its my mistake. Now I edited question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSMutableString *tfContent = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

for (int i = 0; i<4; i++) {

     [tfContent appendString:@"ę́"];

      NSLog(@"%@",tfContent);
}
```

You will get expected output.